# Find the kind of progression

Tags: arithmetic, geometric-progressions

The four positive numbers a,b,c,d are in arithmetic progression.What is the progression sequence of abc,abd,bcd? I found out the common difference b-a,c-b.. but that does not seem to be of much use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,b,c,d$ are in Arithmetic Progression, dividing each term of an AP by a non-zero term still results in an AP, hence dividing with $abcd$ will still yield an AP.

Hence, $\frac{1}{bcd},\frac{1}{acd},\frac{1}{abd},\frac{1}{abc}$ are in AP.

So, the terms $abc,abd,acd,bcd$ are in HP. It might be a typo, but the sequence you have mentioned is not an HP.

Comment: the answer is Harmonic Progression. Neither AP nor GP

Comment: @GrandAlpha Your question might be missing the $acd$ term.

Comment: so you're saying abc,abd,acd,bcd are in HP but not abc,abd,bcd. I just gave the question as it is from a book.It must be a printing mistake.

Comment: It's something like this - 1,2,3,4 are in AP, then 1,2,3 are also in AP but 1,2,4 are not in AP.